# Google charts format settings

Tags: javascript, web, charts, google-visualization

I use pie chart from google charts.

I need formated percent from ##.##% to ##,# %

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: if you still need help, please edit the question with the latest code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you want to localize your chart?
if so, just use Locales for Google Charts:

```
// Load Google Charts for the German locale.
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], 'language': 'de'});
```

or in polymer:

```
<google-chart lang="de" 
              type="{{chartType}}" 
              data="{{data}}" 
              options="{{options}}"></google-chart>
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale

Answer (score 0):

Use Number formatter of Google chart.
Here is example

```
var formatter
 = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
        {suffix: '%',pattern:'#,##'}
);
formatter.format(data, columnNo); 
// Apply formatter to any column you want
```

Comment: Thank you but this solution I tried but did not work for me. :-(

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way of doing this using Google Charts.

The `Number formatter` is only for data tables and does not influence how a chart is formatted.

One possible workaround would be for you to set the option `{pieSliceText: 'label'}` and then generate your labels to be '##,#%'. This of course requires you to do the math on what those values should be and then set them as the label in the data table.